# How can I group Elements by the Users who own them with Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I have the next class:

```
public class Order {
    private User user;
    private List<Element> elements;
}
```

And I need to create the method which returns the map with elements as `keys` and list of users who own it as `values` using Stream API.

```
private static Map<Element, List<User>> m(List<Order> orders) {
        return orders
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Collectors.mapping(Order::getElements)));
                        
    }
```

For example for

```
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

orders.add(Order.createOrder(user1, List.of(element1, element2, element3)));
orders.add(Order.createOrder(user2, List.of(element3)));
orders.add(Order.createOrder(user3, List.of(element1, element2, element3)));
```

we should get:

```
{element1={user1, user3}, element2={user1, user3}, element3={user1, user2, user3}}
```

I tried to use `Collectors.groupingBy()`, but we have the Orders in the stream, how can I group it by Elements - Users. I am totally stuck here. Will be thankful for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier to do if you introduced an intermediate type that represents a pair of `Element` and `User`:

```
record UserAndElement(User user, Element element) {}
```

Then the logic becomes: flatten the orders into a stream of these `UserAndElement` objects, group by their `element`, and then for each group, get their `user`:

```
return orders
    .stream()
    .flatMap(
        x -> x.getElements()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> new UserAndElement(x.getUser(), e))
    ).collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(UserAndElement::element,
            Collectors.mapping(UserAndElement::user, Collectors.toList())
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Sweeper is perfect. You may also use an anonymous class in the stream not to have to declare a one-time class:

```
    return orders.stream()
            .flatMap(o -> o.elements.stream()
                    .map(e -> new Object() { Element el=e; User u=o.user; })
            )
            .collect(groupingBy(o->o.el,mapping(o->o.u,toList())));
```